# Jpa getSingleResult() behoviour if no entity is there sometimes it's shows exception and sometime it's shows error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, toplink

[image]I went through the document I fount NoResultException - if there is no result ,but when I am executing the query its shows null;

As the single result return type is Object we need to typecast the result into the class Object if we  typecast the null with Object no Exception will arise.

can any one give clarity, when it will give an NoResultException ?

Comment: Can you please add the code ?

Comment: You're going to have to provide a [mcve] to prove that behaviour. It's very basic functionality, so it would be a huge bug (in EclipseLink probably) for that to happen.

Comment: @kayaman for proof i added the image

Comment: @GarimaGupta the code is also available in image

Comment: Can you try BigInteger instead of Long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between the lack of results (no rows) and `NULL`. What you're getting is a single `NULL` result, so no exception should be thrown.

Aggregate functions return `NULL` if there are no rows for which to calculate the aggregate, which makes this a bit convoluted. The query itself (`FROM IptReceiveOrder...`) returns `0` rows, but the `MAX(model.id)` changes that into a single `NULL` row.

Comment: Thank you ,I tested what you told is 100% accurate .